# Instagram login and fetch media

Tags: authentication, instagram

I want to fetch media from instagram dynamically i.e need to login first and then fetch media of that user

How can i fix this.
Please help

Thank you,

Comment: in which language ? which plateform ?

Comment: I want fix this in angularjs. Please help , Thank you

Comment: Excully i followed this angularjs service - http://jsfiddle.net/scyrizales/pC9dH/ , but it just with static client id and i want dynamic client id or access token of login user.